# Problem in identifying the graphics card in Windows

Tags: windows, graphics, windows-10, card

I use Tuf Dash Laptop F15

I saw this when viewing the Warzone graphics settings, which was not pleasant. I noticed that in the game settings the selected graphics card is Intel(R) Iris(R) Xe Graphics.
But if it has to be RTX 3050TI

more information:
When I turn on the laptop, I open the task manager and in the Performance section
I see two graphics cards, one Intel(R) Iris(R) Xe Graphics and the other RTX 3050TI
But after a few moments RTX 3050TI disappears from this list
here after
When I open the device manager in the Display Adapter section
Intel(R) Iris(R) Xe Graphics card only
It is shown and I also noticed this when the graphics card is not recognized, in the Device Manager in the Software Devices section
Nvidia Platform Controllers And Framework is disabled and after enabling it, nothing is done (the graphics card is not recognized)

I am not fluent in English, I apologize if I use wrong words or sentences

Comment: This is a user question, so it's more appropriate for Super-User than the programming forums. That said, your laptop is likely using [nVidia Optimus](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/technologies/optimus/) so the way the device enumeration and selection works is done via nVidia software and not by Windows.

Comment: What is the solution?
Unfortunately, I did not understand due to my lack of command of English